# Rendering a pandas dataframe to html, highlighting specific elements

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am having having trouble with rendering a pandas data frame to html then highlighting certain elements.

I have two pandas dataframes which I am rendering to html:

```
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser

data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

data3 = [1, 2, 6, 4, 5]
data4 = [10, 21, 30, 40, 51]       

#make df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['data', 'points'])
df1['data'] = data1 
df1['points'] = data2 

#make df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['data', 'points'])
df2['data'] = data3
df2['points'] = data4

#render df1
html = df1.to_html()
path = "C:\\path"
file_name = "file.html" #make file name specific to patient and plan name
text_file = open(file_name, "w")
text_file.write("df1 Parameters \n" + html)
text_file.close()

#render df2
html = df2.to_html()
path = "C:\\path"
file_name = "file.html" 
text_file = open(file_name, "a+")
text_file.write("df1 Parameters \n" + html)
text_file.close()
webbrowser.open_new_tab(file_name)
```

This produces the following table in an html file:

[image]

The goal is then to compare each dataframe element in df1 and df2 to see if they are equal or different. Elements that are the same should be highlighted in green and elements that do not match should be highlighted in red. The end result would be an html file showing the colored dataframes like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser

data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

data3 = [1, 2, 6, 4, 5]
data4 = [10, 21, 30, 40, 51]       

#make df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['data', 'points'])
df1['data'] = data1 
df1['points'] = data2 

#make df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['data', 'points'])
df2['data'] = data3
df2['points'] = data4

df_style = df1 == df2

def add_background(s):
    is_diff = df_style[s.name]
    return ['background-color: green' if v else 'background-color: red' for v in is_diff]



#render df1
html = df1.style.apply(add_background).render()
path = "C:\\path"
file_name = "file.html" #make file name specific to patient and plan name
text_file = open(file_name, "w")
text_file.write("df1 Parameters \n" + html)
text_file.close()

#render df2
html = df2.style.apply(add_background).render()
path = "C:\\path"
file_name = "file.html" 
text_file = open(file_name, "a+")
text_file.write("df1 Parameters \n" + html)
text_file.close()
webbrowser.open_new_tab(file_name)
```

Output:

[image]