# Highlight cell color with Pandas dataframe with logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [25, 12, 15, 14, 19, 23, 25, 29],
                   'B': [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9, 9, 4],
                   'C': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5, 9, 12]})
```

I have one dataframe (above `df`) where I want to highlight cell color with following condition.

If the value of column B is greater than 8 and the value of column C is greater than 5 then only I want to highlight cell color in column B only with green.

I want to apply above specific condition based on two column.

I don't want to highlight in column C. I want to highlight only in B.

Comment: Generally, pandas structures do not support highlighting.  This might be available through a Jupyter Notebook, via HTML/CSS setup; but is not part of the structure itself.  Therefore, if the structure is serialised, the highlighting will be not transferred.

Comment: For formatting, this is a very similar to you exact question and nice solution.  [highlight cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507358/rendering-a-pandas-dataframe-to-html-highlighting-specific-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset` to select the columns you want to compare and then apply on rows.

```py
s = df.style.apply(lambda row: ['color: green', ''] if (row['B'] > 8) & (row['C'] > 5) else ['', ''],
                   axis=1, subset=['B', 'C'])

s.to_html('output.html')
```

[image]